# Problema Authorize MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

mi problema es que por algun razon el Authorize toma una cookie que esta eliminada y me permite hacer put post get lo que sea estando desloguiado usando esa misma cookie desde postman. Les dejo el code del login, logout y del authentication

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">  
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="10" slidingExpiration="true" name="Auth" />
</authentication>



[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [CaptchaValidation("CaptchaCode", "BotCaptcha", "Incorrect CAPTCHA code!")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Localprovider = (AccountMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
            var res = Localprovider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (res)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                var sessionCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Session"];
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var CaptchaError = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => k == "CaptchaCode").Count();
            if (CaptchaError > 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Código de seguridad incorrecto");

            }
        }

        MvcCaptcha.ResetCaptcha("BotCaptcha");
        MvcCaptcha.ResetCaptcha("CaptchaCode");

        return View(model);
    }


        [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        MvcCaptcha.ResetCaptcha("BotCaptcha");
        MvcCaptcha.ResetCaptcha("CaptchaCode");

        ViewBag.Message = "Logout";
        try {

                Response.Cookies.Clear();
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                HttpCookie c = new HttpCookie("Session");
                c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);

                Response.Cookies.Add(c);
                Session.Clear();
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
            }
        catch
        {

        }
        return View("Logout");
    }
```

Comment: Revisa tu configuración del web.config, prueba a eliminar el módulo de FormsAuthentication. En tu caso <authentication mode="Forms"> .
También comprueba que estas usando el Authorize original que viene por .net y no está siendo sobreescrito

Comment: Probe las dos cosas y ninguna funciono

Comment: Genera conflicto si yo uso authorize de distantas librerias? porque en el controller del login osea en homecontroller uso authorize de System.web.mvc y en los otros controladores uso Authorize de System.web.http  porque uso web api